# About the velocity of Bloch electrons

Tags: condensed-matter, electrons, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation, speed

In a crystal, an electron's wavefunction satisfies the equation
\begin{eqnarray}
H\psi_{n,k}(x)=E_n(k)\psi_{n,k}(x),
\end{eqnarray}
where $n$ is the band index and $k$ is the reduced wave vector. Hence, the wavefunction satisfying the Schrodinger's equation should be
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi(t)=\psi_{n,k}(x)e^{-iE_n(k)t/\hbar}.
\end{eqnarray}

The mean velocity of the electron is defined as
\begin{eqnarray}
v=\frac{d}{dt}\left<{\psi(t)}\right|x\left|\psi(t)\right>.
\end{eqnarray}

In the textbook, the velocity is related to the gradient of the $E_n(k)$ with respect to the wave vector, i.e., 
\begin{eqnarray}
v=\frac{1}{\hbar}\partial_kE_n(k).
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore, the electrons moves forever if the partial is not zero.

However, if we directly calculate the velocity
\begin{eqnarray}
v=\frac{d}{dt}\int dx \psi_{n,k}^*(x)e^{iE_n(k)t/\hbar}x\psi_{n,k}(x)e^{-iE_{n}(k)t/\hbar}=0.
\end{eqnarray}

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Since Bloch functions are time invariant solutions extending through the entire crystal, why would you assume there is a net velocity associated with one?

Comment: I am confusing, too. If we calculate the velocity as follows, $v=<\partial_t\psi(t)|x|\psi(t)>+<\psi(t)|x|\partial_t\psi(t)>=i<\psi(t)|[H,r]|\psi(t)>=<\psi(t)|p|\psi(t)>/m$, where $p=-i\partial_x$

Comment: You can check that $v$ can be nonzero by using the formula above. Consider $H=p^2/(2m)$ and the eigenstate $e^{ipx}$. @Jon Custer

Answer (score 4):

I think that the simple answer here is that $m\frac{d}{dt} \langle x\rangle\ne\langle p\rangle$. The first is proportional to the rate of change of the expectation value of the position, and the second is the expectation value of the quantum-mechanical momentum. They are different in subtle but important ways.

Look at the simplest example of what could be a bloch wavefunction: the momentum eigenstate $|\psi\rangle~e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$.  It's a momentum eigenstate with momentum eigenvalue $\hbar k$ as expected:

$$
p|\psi\rangle=pe^{i(kx-\omega t)} = -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}e^{i(kx-\omega t)}=\hbar k|\psi\rangle
$$

However,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\langle x\rangle=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\text{all}}e^{i(kx-\omega t)}xe^{-i(kx-\omega t)}dx=\frac{d}{dt}\int_\text{all}xdx=0
$$
The integral is clearly not well behaved, which might have you woried, but it's also clearly not time-dependent, so I think it's fair to just call it zero. More mathematically versed physicists might have something more intelligent to say about the divergence of the integral. Regardless, it's clearly not $\propto k$. This is also not a surprise for several reasons.

- It is generically true that for any energy eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$, $\frac{d}{dt}\langle x\rangle=0$, this follows from the definition of an energy eigenstate. For more well-behaved cases this usually implies that the momentum distribution of the eigenstate must be even (that can probably be traced to only $p^2$ appearing in the kinetic energy), but in the case the wavefunction extends to infinity the relation above holds even for non-even momentum distributions.
- Bloch wavefunctions oscillate off to infinity, so the expected position (i.e. your integral before taking the derivative) is not well-defined. It therefore seems ill-suited to try to define a velocity based on the change in the expected position. This definition is a very classical one: It describes how your measurements evolve with time. The particle's position don't evolve with time because at t=0, the particle is everywhere, and at $t=t_0$, the particle is still just everywhere.

Comment: There is a formula in  Messiah's book "Quantum Mechanics" (page 319),  which states $\frac{d}{dt}<A>=\frac{d}{dt}<\psi_H|A_H|\psi_H>=<\psi_H|\frac{dA_H}{dt}|\psi_H>$, where the subscript $H$ means the Hersenberg picture. From the formula, it follows that $\frac{d}{dt}<\psi(t)|x|\psi(t)>=<\psi(t)|p|\psi(t)>$.

Comment: Noting that $\frac{d}{dt}x_H=i[\textrm{Hamiltonian},x_H]=p_H/m$, you can derive the equality. I think the problem may be that the integral $<\psi(t)|x|\psi(t)>$ is divergence, since the crystal is deemed to be infinite large. However, it is then difficult to imagine what happens to a finite large crystal. For a finite one, the integral may be well defined, so the problem emerges again. @aquirdturtle

Comment: I've thought about this some more and better fleshed out my thoughts above.

Comment: You're trying to use a relation in the Heisenberg picture to justify the same thing in the Schrodinger picture. What is $x_H(t)$ in the Heisenberg picture? I haven't tried this but I suspect you will find either poorly defined behavior or you will find that taking it's derivative looks to come out to zero anyways.

Comment: also btw you can use \rangle and langle for bra and ket notation. e.g. $\langle A\rangle$ vs $<A>$