# Electron dynamics in a periodic potential: Why wavepackets? Why $\vec{v}=(1/\hbar)\nabla_{\vec{k}}E_n$ is its group velocity?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrons, electronic-band-theory, dispersion

Electrons in a periodic potential, $V(\vec{ r})$, satisfying $V(\vec{r}+\vec{R}) = V(\vec{ r})$,  are described by Bloch states $$\psi_{n,\vec{k}}(\vec{r})=e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}u_{n,\vec{k}}(\vec{r}), \quad u_{n,\vec{k}}(\vec{r}+\vec{R}) = u_{n,\vec{k}}(\vec{r}),\quad \forall\vec{R}$$ which are eigenstates of the periodic potential. If $E_n(\vec{k})$ is the energy of an electron in the $n$th band with crystal momentum $\hbar k$, the quantity $$\vec{v}(\vec{k})=\frac{1}{\hbar}\nabla_{\vec{k}}E_n(\vec{k}),$$ strictly speaking, gives the expectation value of the velocity operator, ($-i\hbar\nabla/m$), in the Bloch state $\psi_{n,\vec{k}}$ i.e. $$\vec{v}(\vec{k})\equiv \frac{1}{m}\langle\psi_{n,\vec{k}}|-i\hbar\nabla|\psi_{n,\vec{k}}\rangle.$$ This is rigorous. So far there are no wavepackets and electrons are described by delocalized Bloch waves.

However, when one talks about the semiclassical dynamics of electrons, one describes the electrons not in terms of delocalized Bloch waves but by a somewhat localized wavepacket. Why is this so? The justification of this is not clear to me. In addition, the wavepacket is so constructed that its group velocity is equal to the $\vec{v}(\vec{k})$ given above. The justification of this part is also not clear.

In short, the question is: Why wavepackets? Then, why $\vec{v}=(1/\hbar)\nabla_{\vec{k}}E_n(\vec{k})$ is its group velocity of that packet?

Comment: The semiclassical approximation is when we can take $x$ and $p$ as both simultaneously well-defined. This is never truly possible in a quantum system because of the uncertainty relation $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar/2$. It stands to reason that semiclassics will be most well-defined when the uncertainty relation is saturated, i.e., $\Delta x \Delta p = \hbar/2$. This is exactly true only for Gaussian wavepackets
$$
\psi(x) \propto \exp(-(x-X)^2/a + i P x),
$$
where the factor $a$ quantifies the [squeezedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeezed_coherent_state) of the wavepacket. So Gaussian

Comment: It can be demonstrated by applying the Hellmann-Feynman theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem, with $H_{u}(\vec{r},\vec{p},\vec{k})=\frac{1}{2m}(\vec{p}+\hbar \vec{k})^{2}+V(\vec{r})$

Comment: Closely related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370669/389318 Useful background https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/663974/389318

Comment: @TheTiler Do you mean the derivation of the expression of $\vec{v}(\vec{k})$? I know how to derive it (though not from the F-H theorem). My question is different. How do you associate this expression with a group velocity? Where does a wavepacket come here?

Comment: If you take $E = \hbar \omega$, then the formula is exactly that of the group velocity. I guess that is justification for calling the quantity as group velocity.

Comment: @Solidification: All we have to do is make the primitive cell of the lattice tend towards zero, which finally produces a potential V(r ) taking the same value everywhere.In this limit, the length of any vector $\vec{K}\in \tilde{\mathcal{B}}$ tends towards infinity, i.e. we obtain the Laplace transform (k=n/P)...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Comment: @Bio I went through a few books. It is not as simple as that. The semiclassical dynamics of electrons in a periodic potential indeed describe the electron as a wavepacket (superposition of Bloch states). I need an explanation for this.

Comment: Can you explain your note added? I don't understand. Yes, in a semiclassical treatment you use wave packets. But reading your last comment, it seems you now changed the purpose of the question...You should state your question as clear as possible. What you assume and know and what not.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Let me know if this is clearer.

Comment: *"...when one talks about the semiclassical dynamics of electrons, one describes the electrons not in terms of delocalized Bloch waves but by a somewhat localized wavepacket..."* Who is this "one" you are referring to? What are "somewhat localized" wave packets? You just mean wave packets, or what? Is there some reference or textbook or set of lecture notes you are referring to or following along with?

Comment: @hft I thought it was very common which is why I didn't give any references. But yes, I looked at textbooks on Solid State Physics by Ibach and Luth, and by Aschroft and Mermin.

Comment: @Solidification OK, but you just can't ask a question like *"Why wavepackets?"* and expect any kind of reasonable answer. I'm trying to understand what you are asking about and I don't get it. I think if you could edit your question to really try and clarify it would be helpful. I'm not sure if anyone else can just answer, but I don't think I can.

Comment: I guess one answer is that, by definition $\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}=v$, just by the canonical Hamiltonian equations of motions, but I feel that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @hft I think if you build wave packets from Bloch states --as superpositions of states with $k$-vectors near some $k_0$-- you will see that the group velocity of this wave packet is indeed just $\partial_k E$. IIRC Ashcroft & Mermin discusses this. The answer to "why wave packets?" however is more complicated, depending on what one wants to take as granted.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Could you please turn it into an answer?

Comment: Sorry I don't have much time right now. But what is wrong with e.g. the explanation and discussion in A&M?

Answer (score 2):

> ...the quantity
> $$\vec{v}(\vec{k})=\frac{1}{\hbar}\nabla_{\vec{k}}E_n(\vec{k}),$$ ...
> ...
> $$= \frac{1}{m}\langle\psi_{n,\vec{k}}|-i\hbar\nabla|\psi_{n,\vec{k}}\rangle.$$

Yes, this is derived in Ashcroft and Mermin's Appendix E.

> So far there are no wavepackets and electrons are described by delocalized Bloch waves.

Yes, and remember that you can roughly think of Bloch waves in a periodic potential as analogous to plane waves for free particles (no potential).

> However, when one talks about the semiclassical dynamics of electrons, one describes the electrons not in terms of delocalized Bloch waves but by a somewhat localized wavepacket. Why is this so?

Both Bloch waves and plane waves are completely delocalized; they have non-zero amplitudes everywhere in space, so they can not describe a localized particle.

In order to describe a localized particle in a periodic potential one can use a wave packet of Bloch waves, just like one can use a wave packet of plane waves to describe a localized free particle. Both Bloch waves and plane waves are complete sets of functions, so the choice is a matter of convenience. Bloch waves can be more convenient to use when the problem statement includes a periodic (non-constant) potential.

> In short, the question is: Why wavepackets?

Because we have to use wave packets to describe localized particles. Plane waves and Bloch waves are delocalized and unphysical, in the sense that they are unnormalizable (unless you put them in a box). For example, with plane waves, the probability amplitude to find the particle *anywhere* in space is:
$$
P_{pl}(\vec r) = |e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r}|^2 = 1\;.
$$

Or, if we use "box normalization" where the box has a size $V$, the probability amplitude is still constant and the same everywhere in space:
$$
P_{pl,V}(\vec r) = \frac{1}{V}\;.
$$

Similarly, with Bloch waves, the probability amplitude is:
$$
P_{bl}(\vec r) = |e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r}u(\vec r)|^2 = |u(\vec r)|^2\;,
$$
which has the same non-zero values in any unit cell in space, since $u(\vec r +\vec R)=u(\vec r)$.

We have grown used to thinking of plane waves as describing free particles, but really they do not; they happen to solve the free-particle time-independent Schrödinger equation, but they are not normalizable (unless forced into a box). But wave packets made up of plane waves can be normalized. Similarly, wave packets made up of Bloch waves can be normalized.

> Then, why $\vec{v}=(1/\hbar)\nabla_{\vec{k}}E_n(\vec{k})$ is its group velocity of that packet?

Suppose you have some physical/normalizable wave packet $\Psi(\vec r, 0)$ where
$$
\Psi(\vec r, 0 ) = \sum_{n\vec k}c_{n\vec k}e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r}u_{n\vec k }(\vec r)\;.
$$

The time evolution is straight forward to figure out since we expanded in terms of Bloch waves:
$$
\Psi(\vec r, t) = \sum_{n\vec k}c_{n\vec k}e^{-iE_{n}(\vec k) t}e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r}u_{n,\vec k }(\vec r)\;.
$$

Now suppose that the packet is peaked about some specific $\vec k = \vec k_0$ and $n=n_0$ and write:
$$
\Psi(\vec r, t) \approx e^{-i(E_{n_0}(\vec k_0)+\left.\frac{\partial E_{n_0}}{\partial \vec k}\right|_{\vec k_0}\cdot (\vec k - \vec k_0)+\ldots) t}e^{i\vec k_0 \cdot \vec r}\sum_{\vec k} c_{n_0,\vec k}e^{i(\vec k - \vec k_0)\cdot r}u_{n_0,\vec k }(\vec r)\;,
$$
where we can think of $c_{n_0\vec k}$ as something like $e^{-\alpha(\vec k - \vec k_0)^2}$ so that only $\vec k$ values near $\vec k_0$ are important for large $\alpha$. Continuing, we can thus write
$$
\Psi(\vec r, t)\approx e^{-i\vec k_0\cdot (\vec r + \vec v_0 t)}e^{-i E_{n_0}(\vec k_0)t}A(\vec r)\;,
$$
where
$$
\vec v_0 \equiv \left.\frac{\partial E_{n_0}(\vec k)}{\partial \vec k}\right|_{\vec k_0}
$$
and where $A(\vec r)$ is some function that is localized and we can think of it as looking something like
$$
A(\vec r) \approx e^{-\frac{r^2}{2\alpha}}\;.
$$

So, our wave packet "looks like" a plane wave, but with $\vec r$ shifted to $\vec r + \vec v_0 t$ and some overall envelope function $A(\vec r)$ keeping it localized.

Comment: I’d also like to add that in many cases that I’m familiar with (like an electron’s cyclotron motion in a magnetic field) the wavepacket interpretation reproduces the classical solution of a point particle sized electron.